# Refresh the page content or the just the search results part like in google

Tags: html, angularjs

After I erase the query I searched on  input field of form-control, results still remain on the page until I refresh the page. Is there a way I can make the content go away when field is cleared?. I  am pulling this data from database at work

```
  <div>
    <input id="NDC_Code" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Enter name"
           ng-model="name" autofocus/>
  </div>
  </br></br>

  <div>
    <input id="address" type="text" class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Enter address"
           ng-model="address" />
  </div>
```

Comment: how does the result model looks like?

Comment: try $scope.results = [] for arrays and $scope.results = {} for objects.

Comment: results are pulled in table data through ng-repeat, I want the table to disappear or the page to be refreshed if input field is cleared

Comment: ok, so if the user clears the inputs right?

Comment: yes if user clears the input the previous query needs to be cleared

Comment: You can check the length of the inputs and hide the results but this won't clear the actual result just hide. I'm think lol

Comment: Here is a starting point. it have a few bugs but is the only soluction i can come up with at the moment. You need a button to search to know if the user already searched before: https://plnkr.co/edit/1sgaYt1Pb3j7r1VSRRH7?p=preview

Comment: Did you have any luck with the example?

Comment: yes it worked @iamrelos thank you

Comment: Ok I will add it to as an answer

Comment: I had one question, since I am trying to implement this concept in my solution. Which function clears the search result, Since I am new to angularjs kind of difficult to figure out

Comment: The showResult, I should of name it display result. Also accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach to it, but maybe someone might have a better approach. So the idea is to have a Search Button like so:

```
<button ng-click="getData()" ng-disabled="!showResult()">search</button>
```

this button will go a get the data and make a boolean flag to true so you can know that the user already searched:

```
$scope.getData = function() {
  // GET DATA
  $scope.results = [{
    name: 'Josh',
    address: '234 nis'
  }, {
    name: 'Chris',
    address: '234 sdf'
  }, {
    name: 'Scott',
    address: '234 nis'
  }, {
    name: 'Pat',
    address: '234 sd'
  }, {
    name: 'Jose',
    address: '234 sd'
  }];


  // USER HAS SEARCHED TO TRUE
  $scope.hasSearched = true;
};
```

now you only display the result if the inputs contain text using a function that returns a boolean, but in that function you also check if the user has searched.  if the user has search and the inputs are empty you clear the results variable:

```
  // RETURNS TRUE OR FALSE IF INPUTS ARE EMPTY AND ALSO CHECKS IF USER HAS SEARCHED TO CLEAR RESULTS
  $scope.showResult = function() {

  if ((!$scope.name && !$scope.address && $scope.hasSearched)) {
    $scope.results = [];

    // USER HAS SEARCHED TO FALSE
    $scope.hasSearched = false;
  }

  return $scope.name && $scope.address;
};
```

Now, this is just my 3 second approach. [Full Code in Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/1sgaYt1Pb3j7r1VSRRH7?p=preview)